# Compare two files and write it to "match" and "nomatch" files

Tags: mainframe, syncsort, dfsort, easytrieve

I have two input files, each with length of 5200 bytes. A seven byte key is used to compare both files, if there is a match then it needs to be written to "match" file but while writing to match file I need a few fields from `infile1` and all other fields from `infile2`.

If there is no match then write to `no match` file.

Is it possible to do it in `sort`? I know it can be easily done using COBOL program but just want to know in `SORT/ICETOOL/Easytrieve Plus (EZTPA00)`.

Answer (score 8):

Since 12,200 people have looked at this question and not got an answer:

DFSORT and SyncSort are the predominant Mainframe sorting products. Their control cards have many similarities, and some differences.

```
JOINKEYS FILE=F1,FIELDS=(key1startpos,7,A)              
JOINKEYS FILE=F2,FIELDS=(key2startpos,7,A)              
JOIN UNPAIRED,F1,F2
REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:1,5200,F2:1,5200)                         
SORT FIELDS=COPY
```

A "JOINKEYS" is made of three Tasks. Sub-Task 1 is the first JOINKEYS. Sub-Task 2 is the second JOINKEYS. The Main Task follows and is where the joined data is processed. In the example above it is a simple COPY operation. The joined data will simply be written to SORTOUT.

The JOIN statement defines that as well as matched records, UNPAIRED F1 and F2 records are to be presented to the Main Task.

The REFORMAT statement defines the record which will be presented to the Main Task. A more efficient example, imagining that three fields are required from F2, is:

```
 REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:1,5200,F2:1,10,30,1,5100,100)
```

Each of the fields on F2 is defined with a start position and a length.

The record which is then processed by the Main task is 5311 bytes long, and the fields from F2 can be referenced by 5201,10,5211,1,5212,100 with the F1 record being 1,5200.

A better way achieve the same thing is to reduce the size of F2 with JNF2CNTL.

```
//JNF2CNTL DD *
  INREC BUILD=(207,1,10,30,1,5100,100)
```

Some installations of SyncSort do not support JNF2CNTL, and even where supported (from Syncsort MFX for z/OS release 1.4.1.0 onwards), it is not documented by SyncSort. For users of 1.3.2 or 1.4.0 an update is available from SyncSort to provide JNFnCNTL support.

It should be noted that JOINKEYS by default SORTs the data, with option EQUALS. If the data for a JOINKEYS file is already in sequence, SORTED should be specified. For DFSORT NOSEQCHK can also be specified if sequence-checking is not required.

```
 JOINKEYS FILE=F1,FIELDS=(key1startpos,7,A),SORTED,NOSEQCHK
```

Although the request is strange, as the source file won't be able to be determined, all unmatched records are to go to a separate output file.

With DFSORT, there is a matching-marker, specified with ? in the REFORMAT:

```
 REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:1,5200,F2:1,10,30,1,5100,100,?)
```

This increases the length of the REFORMAT record by one byte. The ? can be specified anywhere on the REFORMAT record, and need not be specified. The ? is resolved by DFSORT to: B, data sourced from Both files; 1, unmatched record from F1; 2, unmatched record from F2.

SyncSort does not have the match marker. The absence or presence of data on the REFORMAT record has to be determined by values. Pick a byte on both input records which cannot contain a particular value (for instance, within a number, decide on a non-numeric value). Then specify that value as the FILL character on the REFORMAT.

```
 REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:1,5200,F2:1,10,30,1,5100,100),FILL=C'$'
```

If position 1 on F1 cannot naturally have "$" and position 20 on F2 cannot either, then those two positions can be used to establish the result of the match. The entire record can be tested if necessary, but sucks up more CPU time.

The apparent requirement is for all unmatched records, from either F1 or F2, to be written to one file. This will require a REFORMAT statement which includes both records in their entirety:

DFSORT, output unmatched records:

```
  REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:1,5200,F2:1,5200,?)

  OUTFIL FNAMES=NOMATCH,INCLUDE=(10401,1,SS,EQ,C'1,2'),
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=(10401,1,CH,EQ,C'1'),
                    BUILD=(1,5200)),
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=NONE,
                    BUILD=(5201,5200))
```

SyncSort, output unmatched records:

```
  REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:1,5200,F2:1,5200),FILL=C'$'

  OUTFIL FNAMES=NOMATCH,INCLUDE=(1,1,CH,EQ,C'$',
                          OR,5220,1,CH,EQ,C'$'),
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=(1,1,CH,EQ,C'$'),
                    BUILD=(1,5200)),
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=NONE,
                    BUILD=(5201,5200))
```

The coding for SyncSort will also work with DFSORT.

To get the matched records written is easy.

```
  OUTFIL FNAMES=MATCH,SAVE
```

SAVE ensures that all records not written by another OUTFIL will be written here.

There is some reformatting required, to mainly output data from F1, but to select some fields from F2. This will work for either DFSORT or SyncSort:

```
  OUTFIL FNAMES=MATCH,SAVE,
     BUILD=(1,50,10300,100,51,212,5201,10,263,8,5230,1,271,4929)
```

The whole thing, with arbitrary starts and lengths is:

DFSORT

```
  JOINKEYS FILE=F1,FIELDS=(1,7,A)              
  JOINKEYS FILE=F2,FIELDS=(20,7,A)    

  JOIN UNPAIRED,F1,F2

  REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:1,5200,F2:1,5200,?)                         

  SORT FIELDS=COPY    

  OUTFIL FNAMES=NOMATCH,INCLUDE=(10401,1,SS,EQ,C'1,2'),
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=(10401,1,CH,EQ,C'1'),
                    BUILD=(1,5200)),
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=NONE,
                    BUILD=(5201,5200))

  OUTFIL FNAMES=MATCH,SAVE,
     BUILD=(1,50,10300,100,51,212,5201,10,263,8,5230,1,271,4929)
```

SyncSort

```
  JOINKEYS FILE=F1,FIELDS=(1,7,A)              
  JOINKEYS FILE=F2,FIELDS=(20,7,A)              

  JOIN UNPAIRED,F1,F2

  REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:1,5200,F2:1,5200),FILL=C'$'                         

  SORT FIELDS=COPY    

  OUTFIL FNAMES=NOMATCH,INCLUDE=(1,1,CH,EQ,C'$',
                          OR,5220,1,CH,EQ,C'$'),
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=(1,1,CH,EQ,C'$'),
                    BUILD=(1,5200)),
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=NONE,
                    BUILD=(5201,5200))

  OUTFIL FNAMES=MATCH,SAVE,
     BUILD=(1,50,10300,100,51,212,5201,10,263,8,5230,1,271,4929)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had used JCL about 2 years back so cannot write a code for you but here is the idea;

1. Have 2 steps
2. First step will have ICETOOl where you can write the matching records to matched file.
3. Second you can write a file for mismatched by using SORT/ICETOOl or by just file operations.

again i apologize for solution without code, but i am out of touch by 2 yrs+

Comment: Don't need two steps. Don't need ICETOOL. SORT with JOINKEYS will do it. From  what is described, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In Eztrieve it's really easy, below is an example how you could code it:

```
//STEP01   EXEC PGM=EZTPA00                                        
//FILEA    DD DSN=FILEA,DISP=SHR   
//FILEB    DD DSN=FILEB,DISP=SHR
//FILEC    DD DSN=FILEC.DIF,    
//            DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),                             
//            SPACE=(CYL,(100,50),RLSE),                           
//            UNIT=PRMDA,                                          
//            DCB=(RECFM=FB,LRECL=5200,BLKSIZE=0)                  
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                                             
//SRTMSG   DD SYSOUT=*                                             
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                             
//SYSIN    DD *                                                    
 FILE FILEA                                                        
   FA-KEY       1   7 A                                         
   FA-REC1      8  10 A
   FA-REC2     18   5 A

 FILE FILEB                                                        
   FB-KEY       1   7 A                                         
   FB-REC1      8  10 A                                         
   FB-REC2     18   5 A                                         

 FILE FILEC                                                        

 FILE FILED                                                        
   FD-KEY       1   7 A                                         
   FD-REC1      8  10 A                                         
   FD-REC2     18   5 A                                         


 JOB INPUT (FILEA KEY FA-KEY FILEB KEY FB-KEY)                     
   IF MATCHED            
      FD-KEY   =  FB-KEY                                      
      FD-REC1  =  FA-REC1
      FD-REC2  =  FB-REC2
      PUT FILED
   ELSE
      IF FILEA
         PUT FILEC FROM FILEA                                         
      ELSE
         PUT FILEC FROM FILEB
      END-IF                                         
   END-IF                                                          
/*
```

Comment: FILEC is going to be pretty useless, as you won't know what has come from where. TS/OP should have been asked this. Back in 2009. Doesn't deal with duplicates. Fortunately, let's just say no duplicates. Did you ensure that the files are in order by key? No? Won't work then. The program can also be made to work for variable-length records. Other than these things, this looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Though its really long back this question was posted, I wish to answer as it might help others. This can be done easily by means of `JOINKEYS` in a SINGLE step. Here goes the pseudo code:

- Code `JOINKEYS PAIRED(implicit)` and get both the records via reformatting filed. If there is NO match from either of files then append/prefix some special character say `'$'`
- Compare via IFTHEN for `'$'`, if exists then it doesnt have a paired record, it'll be written into unpaired file and rest to paired file.

Please do get back incase of any questions.

Comment: If you only deal with paired records, you are not going to get any mismatches. If DFSORT instead of SyncSort, don't need the '$', but can use the built-in match marker ? (that's what the match marker is, it is not a question).

Answer (score 0):

```
//STEP01   EXEC SORT90MB                        
//SORTJNF1 DD DSN=INPUTFILE1,   
//            DISP=SHR                          
//SORTJNF2 DD DSN=INPUTFILE2,   
//            DISP=SHR                          
//SORTOUT  DD DSN=MISMATCH_OUTPUT_FILE, 
//            DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE),             
//            UNIT=TAPE,                        
//            DCB=(RECFM=FB,BLKSIZE=0),         
//            DSORG=PS                          
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                          
//SYSIN    DD *                                 
  JOINKEYS FILE=F1,FIELDS=(1,79,A)              
  JOINKEYS FILE=F2,FIELDS=(1,79,A)              
  JOIN UNPAIRED,F1,ONLY                         
  SORT FIELDS=COPY                              
/*
```

Comment: This won't get any matches at all, and mismatches only from F1.