# Compare two files and include both match and non match records

Tags: mainframe, dfsort, syncsort

I need to merge two files into one .
Suppose I have 2 input files FILE1 and FILE2. And I need to  non-matching records from FILE1 and FILE2 into FILE 3 as well as I want to write matching records also into FILE3.If there is matching based on key in FILE1 and FILE2 then matching record to be written must be picked from FILE1/FILE2 on basis of some condition.

The key position in both the Input Files is same.

Can anybody please help me to write SORTCARD, how Can I get this in single step in SyncSort or DFSort??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two files and write it to "match" and "nomatch" files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792432/compare-two-files-and-write-it-to-match-and-nomatch-files)

Comment: Thanks Bill. My problem was not exactly the same as you mentioned in link but helped me to reach at solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my solution using following sort card:

```
    JOINKEYS F1=IN1,FIELDS=(1,7,A,13,7,A)                     
    JOINKEYS F2=IN2,FIELDS=(1,7,A,13,7,A)                     
    JOIN UNPAIRED,F1,F2                                       
    REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:1,239,F2:1,239,?)                     
    OPTION COPY                                               
    OUTFIL FNAMES=OUT1,INCLUDE=(479,1,SS,EQ,C'1,2'),          
    IFTHEN=(WHEN=(479,1,CH,EQ,C'1'),                    
          BUILD=(1,239,479,1)),                       
    IFTHEN=(WHEN=NONE,                                  
          BUILD=(240,239,479,1))                      
    OUTFIL FNAMES=OUT2,INCLUDE=(479,1,SS,EQ,C'B'),            
    IFTHEN=(WHEN=(111,1,FS,EQ,NUM,AND,175,1,FS,EQ,NUM),
           BUILD=(1,239)),                            
    IFTHEN=(WHEN=(350,1,FS,EQ,NUM,AND,414,1,FS,EQ,NUM),
           BUILD=(240,239)),                          
    IFTHEN=(WHEN=NONE,                                 
          BUILD=(1,239))
```

Comment: For OUT2 you can use CH instead of SS, then on OUT1 use SAVE instead of the INCLUDE. On OUT2 you can use IFOUTLEN=239, and in the second IFTHEN combine with the negative of the first IFTHEN, then remove the first and third IFTHENs.

Comment: The titles are almost word-for-word the same. It is the top of the search-engine results when you use your keywords.

Comment: @BillWoodger, I agree the title is almost similar sorry for that. One thing can you explain how I can remove first and third if then using IFOUTLEN=239. I checked the DFSORT manual, IFOUTLEN overrides the OUTREC LRECL for IFTHEN.I think I am already giving length of records in BUILD i think.

Comment: Glad you agree. The point is, if you use IFOUTLEN you can remove two BUILDs. If you have lots of data, you'll notice the difference. If you don't have lots of data, you'll benefit when you do.

Answer (score 0):

Try using join keys

```
SORT FIELDS=COPY
JOINKEYS FILES=F1,FIELDS=(1,5,A)
JOINKEYS FILES=F2,FIELDS=(1,5,A)
JOIN UNPAIRED,F1,F2
REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:1,6,F2:1,80)
```

in reformat fields, you can mention the fields as you want, i.e.., if you want matching records to be picked from file2 then mention those fileds beside F2:

Comment: And how do you tell there was a match, or a mismatch on F1, or a mismatch on F2?