# File match nomatch

Tags: mainframe, jcl

I have two files say F1 and F2 (both LRECL=37). If F1 and F2 are identical then output file should be empty and if they aren't identical then all records of F1 should be copied in output file. Is there any way this can be achieved thru JCL utility.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two files and write it to "match" and "nomatch" files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792432/compare-two-files-and-write-it-to-match-and-nomatch-files)

Answer (score 0):

The expected result could be achieved in 3 jobsteps.

In the first jobstep, delete and define the output dataset using IEFBR14 utility.

In the second jobstep, compare the datasets F1 & F2 using IEBCOMPR utility. IEBCOMPR returns a code of 00 when the comparison is successful & 08 for an unequal comparison.

In the third jobstep, use the return code from the second jobstep to decide whether to run IEBGENER utility to copy ALL records of F1 dataset.

Hope this helps, please let me know if you've got an alternative that works efficiently.